# Django Rest Framework: Call serializer.save using double underscore

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

When making querysets in Django, you can use the double underscore method, to filter on specific criteria of a model:
E.g. instead of filtering restaurant by their pk like this:

```
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.filter(restaurant=<some_pk>)
```

You can filter them by some attribute of the model like this:

```
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.filter(restaurant__uuid=<some_uuid>)
```

Or

```
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.filter(restaurant__name=<some_name>)
```

Now in function in the api views you (e.g. in get_queryset) you can use this to filter by kwargs of the request:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    restaurants = Restaurant.objects.filter(restaurant__uuid=self.kwargs['uuid'])
    return restaurants
```

Now I want to do the same using serializer.save(). In my perform create I want to call:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(restaurant__uuid=self.request.data['uuid'])
```

This unfortunately throws an error. My workaround is this:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(restaurant__uuid=self.kwargs['uuid'])
    serializer.save(restaurant=restaurant)
```

but this obviously has bad performance, because it needs to do an additional queryset. Is there any way to get it work in one step within serializer.save()?

### Edit

Upon the request I added the restaurant model:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        unique=True
    )
    owner = models.ForeignkeyField(
        Owner,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class Chef(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(
        Restaurant,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    training = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
```

Just to clarify I want to call serializer.save() for a Chef, dynamically giving him the restaurant based on the UUID.

Comment: Add your `Restaurant` model code snippet. `restaurant` is a foreign key attribute in the `Restaurant` model itself?

Comment: @ritesh-agrawal Thank you for your help. I edited the post for clarification.

Comment: So, are you trying to implement `ChefSerializer` or `RestaurantSerializer`? Is it ChefSeralizer and you're trying to retrieve and update related Restaurant object.

Comment: @ boris-burkov No, the serializers are done. (Maybe it's possible using the serializers.) What I'm trying to do is calling `serializer.save() `within the view, and giving the data into the `serializer.save()` method as an argument.

Simply put I want to create a Chef object that works at the restaurant, by passiing the restaurant data as an argument to the save function.

Comment: I think atleast primary key is required to directly create entry in `Chef` model instance. By default `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` is used for foreign keys in serializer. There is one more field `SlugRelatedField` which allows target representation using a particular field. But make sure, it saves that extra query because by default serializer queries to check if object is present or not. You can experiment though.

Comment: As far as I know UUID is also used for unique target identification :)

Comment: Definitely we can uniquely identify target by uuid but primary key is used to link two tables rows. In your case, if you have id of restaurant, then you can directly write `serializer.save(restaurant=restaurant_id)` because anything passed in the save argument directly appends in the `validated_data`.

Comment: Okay :) The question is: is there a way to call serializer.save(restaurant__name=<restaurantname>)? because the other thing for me has bad performance :(

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with a single underscore.

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(restaurant_uuid=self.request.data['uuid'])
```